# Not able to install "pip"

Tags: python, bash, pip

So I am trying to download pip for gRPC as given on grpc.io website. And I read many questions related to that but I am still not able to download pip. I am using mac with python (version 2.7.10).

when I write pip on console. It gives below error :-
`bash: pip: command not found`

I checked few questions and they were recommending `easy_install pip` but didn't work either.

One of my colleague recommended to use `brew install pip` as we have installed almost everything using brew.Got below error when I did that.

`Error: No available formula with the name "pip" 
Homebrew provides pip via:`brew install python`. However you will then
have two Pythons installed on your Mac, so alternatively you can install
pip via the instructions at:
  https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/`

I went on this link and it says to run `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` and after that, run this `python get-pip.py`.

I did this but it gives below thing :

```
Collecting pip
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 18.1
Uninstalling pip-18.1:
Successfully uninstalled pip-18.1
Rolling back uninstall of pip
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Could you all suggest a way to download and use pip?

**UPDATE**

Earlier I was trying to install using **sudo easy_install pip**, it was giving an error. Now I tried doing it, it got installed. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Maybe you're missing a `sudo` when doing the install?

Answer (score 1):

follow the following steps:

1. go to pypi [website](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) pip offcial account .
2. Download the source file. `pip-18.1.tar.gz`
3. Extract the file.
4. in command prompt run command :
           `python setup.py install`

pip is installed now.